# Android Studio TabLayout & Recycler View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have TabLayout in my app. One of the tabs contains a tabHost and all the tabs inside the tabHost contain a RecyclerView. When I click any of the rows inside any RecyclerView I want a new Activity to launch with the row details but the different Tabs of the TabLayout should be as it is (Like Tabbed Control in iOS).

Can anyone please help on the same ? Any example, code snippet would be welcome.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: so I have created 3 tabs using TabLayout .... the first tab has Tabhost with 3 further tabs....and each of these contain a RecyclerView .... when a click on any one of the rows of the Recycler View I want to open a new Activity inside the original 1st tab created using TabLayout ?

Comment: Putting a question mark at the end of a statement doesn't make it a question.

Comment: If you can't help me.. its fine...but I would request to stop making stupid comments here...there are other websites for stuff like that eg. FB and Twitter to name a few....perhaps you have heard of them!!!

Comment: I'm just trying to help you have a good question. If I offended you, however, I'm sorry. I'll stay out of this.

Comment: I didn't mean to be a jerk.